# I'm making a brick breaker game and was wondering if there is a way I can put these bricks under one variable

Tags: python, variables, pygame

These are the bricks I have made for my game. Stack Overflow is not letting me put all of my bricks so these are 1/3 of them. The total amount is 60 (3 rows of 20).

```
#Bricks    
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (0,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (40,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (80,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (120,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (160,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (200,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (240,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (280,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (320,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (360,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (400,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (440,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (480,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (520,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (560,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (600,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (640,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (680,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (720,65,40,20), 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (760,65,40,20), 0)
```

Is it possible I can put these bricks under one variable and also shorten this code? You're help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `for x in range(0, some_number, 40): pygame.draw.rect(screen, (blue), (x,65,40,20), 0)`?

Comment: What is "some_number" suppose to be?

Comment: Whatever your maximum is. 760 in your question but you said you couldn't post your whole code. The point is that it increments in 40s from zero to your max.

Comment: Only two bricks show up.

Comment: Only 2 bricks show up, the amount is suppose to be 3 rows of 20 which is 60 in total, help.

Comment: You could use a simple nested for loop structure for that.

Comment: Could you write out the code for me?

Comment: This is really basic stuff which most tutorials out there will teach you. You just have to put a for loop inside the body of another for loop. I also recommend creating a list filled with `pygame.Rect`s, because they can be used for the collision detection, and then just loop over this list and pass the rects to `pygame.draw.rect` to draw them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use nested `for` loops to create list with all bricks.

I will use [pygame.Rect()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to keep position and size because I will use it to check collision.

```
all_bricks = []

for y in range(65, 106, 20):
    for x in range(0, 761, 40):
        brick_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 40, 20)
        all_bricks.append(brick_rect)
```

and then you can draw them using one `for` loop

```
for brick_rect in all_bricks:    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, brick_rect, 0)
```

or check collisions

```
untouched_bricks = []

for brick_rect in all_bricks:    
    if not ball_rect.colliderect(brick_rect):
        untouched_bricks.append(brick_rect)
    #else:
    #    print("Brick touched")

# keep only untouched bricks
all_bricks = unbreaked_bricks
```

---

To keep position and different color for every brick separately you will need more complex structure:

- list - ie. `[blue, pygame.Rect(x, y, 40, 20), ...]`
- dictionary - ie. `{"color": blue, "rect": pygame.Rect(x, y, 40, 20), "other": ...}`)
- class

Comment: Thanks this is a big help but I do have one problem. Everything worked except the collision. When I try to run the program I get this error:                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user_000\Desktop\project\Brick Breaker - Game Project.py", line 135, in <module>
    all_bricks = unbreaked_bricks
NameError: name 'unbreaked_bricks' is not defined

Comment: Help would be appreciated.